# Prove that $\mathcal{O}_{X\times Y}$ is a topology on $X\times Y$. ("Basic Manifold Theory" (in Japanese) by Yukio Matsumoto)

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am reading "Basic Manifold Theory" (in Japanese) by Yukio Matsumoto.
The author wrote the following fact is easy to prove.
But I cannot prove the following fact.
The author didn't write about basis for a topology in this book.

> Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{O}_X$ be a topology on $X$.
> Let $Y$ be a set and $\mathcal{O}_Y$ be a topology on $Y$.
> Let $\mathcal{O}_{X\times Y}$ be a set which consists of all unions of sets of the form $U \times V$, where $U \in \mathcal{O}_X$ and $V \in \mathcal{O}_Y$.
> Then, $\mathcal{O}_{X\times Y}$ is a topology on $X\times Y$.

> My attempt:
> 1.
> $X\in\mathcal{O}_X$.
> $Y\in\mathcal{O}_Y$.
> So, $X\times Y\in\mathcal{O}_{X\times Y}.$
> $\emptyset\in\mathcal{O}_X$.
> So, $\emptyset=\emptyset\times Y\in\mathcal{O}_{X\times Y}.$
> 2.
> Let $A,B\in\mathcal{O}_{X\times Y}.$
> Then we can write $A=\bigcup_{\lambda_1\in\Lambda_1} U_{\lambda_1}\times V_{\lambda_1}$, where $U_{\lambda_1}\in\mathcal{O}_X$ and $V_{\lambda_1}\in\mathcal{O}_Y$ for any $\lambda_1\in\Lambda_1$.
> Then we can write $B=\bigcup_{\lambda_2\in\Lambda_2} U_{\lambda_2}\times V_{\lambda_2}$, where $U_{\lambda_2}\in\mathcal{O}_X$ and $V_{\lambda_2}\in\mathcal{O}_Y$ for any $\lambda_2\in\Lambda_2$.
> Then $A\cap B=\bigcup_{(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\in\Lambda_1\times\Lambda_2}(U_{\lambda_1}\times V_{\lambda_1})\cap(U_{\lambda_2}\times V_{\lambda_2})=\bigcup_{(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\in\Lambda_1\times\Lambda_2}(U_{\lambda_1}\cap U_{\lambda_2})\times(V_{\lambda_1}\cap V_{\lambda_2}).$
> $U_{\lambda_1}\cap U_{\lambda_2}\in\mathcal{O}_X$ for any $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\in\Lambda_1\times\Lambda_2.$
> $V_{\lambda_1}\cap V_{\lambda_2}\in\mathcal{O}_Y$ for any $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\in\Lambda_1\times\Lambda_2.$
> So, $A\cap B\in\mathcal{O}_{X\times Y}.$
> 3.
> Let $A_\mu\in\mathcal{O}_{X\times Y}$ for any $\mu\in M.$
> Then we can write $A_\mu=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda_\mu} U_{\mu\lambda}\times V_{\mu\lambda}.$
> Then $\bigcup_{\mu\in M}A_\mu=\bigcup_{\mu\in M}(\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda_\mu} U_{\mu\lambda}\times V_{\mu\lambda}).$

I want to write $\bigcup_{\mu\in M}A_\mu=\bigcup_{\lambda} U_{\lambda}\times V_{\lambda}$ but I can't.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I believe that you are looking to re-express your indexing set as follows: Define $\Lambda = \bigcup_{\mu \in M}\Lambda_\mu$. Then $U_\lambda \in \mathcal{O}_X$ and $V_\lambda \in \mathcal{O}_Y$ for $\lambda \in \Lambda$ and $\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}U_{\lambda}\times V_{\lambda} \in \mathcal{O}_{X \times Y}$. But this isn't really necessary since you have already written an expression for a union of sets of the form $U \times V$, where $U \in \mathcal{O}_X$ and $V \in \mathcal{O}_Y$.

Comment: @MenanderI Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Is my answer ok?

Let $\Lambda:=\{U_{\mu\lambda}\times V_{\mu\lambda}\mid\mu\in M,\lambda\in\Lambda_\mu\}.$
Let $B_\lambda:=\lambda$ for $\lambda\in\Lambda.$
Then, $\bigcup_{\mu\in M}A_\mu=\bigcup_{\mu\in M}(\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda_\mu} U_{\mu\lambda}\times V_{\mu\lambda})=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}B_\lambda$.
And $\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}B_\lambda\in\mathcal{O}_{X\times Y}.$